# JSX access property object in condition Unexpected token

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

My example :

```
var props = {
    status:'root'
};

class ButtonYii extends React.Component{

    render(){

        return (
          { props.status? <p>admin</p> : <p>user</p>}
            )

    }
};
```

How in JSX syntax I can write condition with access property of object ?

Onlн this alternative?

```
isAdmin(){
        return props.status== 'root'
    }

    render(){

        return (
          isAdmin() ?<p>admin</p> : <p>user</p>
            )

    }
```

Comment: need clarity what exactly you want to achieve?

Comment: @NarasimhaReddy, I think you havent read the question : _How in JSX syntax I can write condition with access property of object ?_  , for this question I don't think, we need to worry about hard code as OP want syntax of conditional rendering

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
let props = {
  status: 'root'
};

class ButtonYii extends React.Component {
  render() {
    let userName = (props.status == 'root') ? 'admin' : 'user';

    return (
      <p>{userName}</p>
    );

  }
}
```

Or

```
let props = {
  status: 'root'
};

class ButtonYii extends React.Component {
  render() {

    return (
      <p>{ (props.status == 'root' ) ? 'admin' : 'user' }</p>
    );

  }
}
```

Comment: Here `props.status` always `root` as you hard coded. then why we need conditional rendering?

Comment: not sure of sue of the condition, just shown how to use condition in react

Comment: Glad to help you :)